# Sqoop not able to map oracle column types to hive column

Tags: hive, sqoop, hortonworks-data-platform

I am sqooping a bunch of Oracle 10g tables in to hive. I am working on Hortonworks HDP2.3 on my cluster.
One of the oracle table with more than 100 columns has a ROW_ID column, which I found out is of type oracle.sql.ROWID.
Sqoop is throwing error :

```
2016-02-04 16:09:19,746 ERROR - [main:] ~ Cannot resolve SQL type -8 (ClassWriter:645)
2016-02-04 16:09:19,747 ERROR - [main:] ~ Cannot resolve SQL type -8 (ClassWriter:645)
2016-02-04 16:09:19,747 ERROR - [main:] ~ No Java type for SQL type -8 for column ROW_ID (ClassWriter:718)
2016-02-04 16:09:19,748 ERROR - [main:] ~ No Java type for SQL type -8 for column ROW_ID (ClassWriter:718)
2016-02-04 16:09:19,749 ERROR - [main:] ~ No Java type for SQL type -8 for column ROW_ID (ClassWriter:798)
2016-02-04 16:09:19,756 ERROR - [main:] ~ Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.NullPointerException (Sqoop:181)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.parseNullVal(ClassWriter.java:1377)
        at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.parseColumn(ClassWriter.java:1402)
        at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.myGenerateParser(ClassWriter.java:1528)
        at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generateParser(ClassWriter.java:1491)
        at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generateClassForColumns(ClassWriter.java:1920)
        at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1736)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:107)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:478)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
```

Is there a way to map this oracle column type to any hive column type or just make it string?

Comment: Basically, an Oracle ROWID stores a *logical position* for a specific row on a specific file block. Over time, the same ROWID may refer to different rows *(older gets deleted, the free space gets reused on insert)* or the same row may be moved to a new ROWID *(table defrag, etc.)* In other words, **using the ROWID type for user data is an absolute and utter perversion**.

Comment: Thanks for info Samson. I am not an Oracle person, so no clue what ROWID is meant for. I was never going to use it in my business logic either. Just wanted to maintain the table definition in hive as close to source as possible. Updating the question title to more generic one as the answer still is relevant to Sqoop users.

Comment: I don't blame you, you're just the "Transporter"  ;-)  Anyway, a ROWID is binary by nature, so the safe way to trasport it is to convert it to Hex or Base64 string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, not sure if this is the right way to do. But anyways.

First I tried `--map-column-hive ROW_ID=String` , it was still complaining the same error.

Then I tried `--map-column-java ROW_ID=String` , it happily downloaded the data from oracle, but was not ready to put it in hive:

```
2016-02-04 16:55:17,655 ERROR - [main:] ~ Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: Hive does not support the SQL type for column ROW_ID
        at org.apache.sqoop.hive.TableDefWriter.getCreateTableStmt(TableDefWriter.java:181)
        at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.importTable(HiveImport.java:188)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:514)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
 (ImportTool:613)
```

Well, finally their combination worked fine.

```
sqoop import .... --map-column-java ROW_ID=String --map-column-hive ROW_ID=String
```

Also, `--split-by` didn't like the ROW_ID either. So I had to use a different column for that.

-Cheers.